# Thread handling techniques in java

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my first professional threaded application, and things are a bit confusing to me.

I need to get a large amount of data from an API, in which I provide an id to three different API end-points, and depending on which is returning a non null value, I have to parse and handle the data.

I have a working version of this, but with out the use of threads, and it is taking too long to complete.

The main idea is that I am using a pool of ids, and trying to connect to the API, inside a loop. Each loop is creating a new Object that handles the connection and the data parsing.

```
public void connect(){
    For(String id:idList){
      String url="...."+id;
      String reply=getData(url);
      if(reply!=null){
         //parse data
         parse(reply);
      } 
    }
}
public void parse(String data){
   //....
}
```

So I thought to give threads a try, in case it speeds thing up.
My attempt so far seems to be working, I can connect and download the data, but I haven’t figured out how to limit the Threads I create, in order to avoid overflow or out of memory errors.
From my research, I saw that I can put newly created threads to sleep if there are too many threads already running, like so: (example from [www.shayanderson.com](http://www.shayanderson.com/java/run-multiple-threads-in-java-and-limit-max-thread-count.htm))

```
public class Test {
      public static final int MAX_THREADS = 3;
      public static int threads_counter = 0;

      public class MyThread extends Thread {
            String name;
            String says;
            private final int REPEATS = 1;
            private final int DELAY = 200;

            public MyThread(String in_name, String in_says) {
                  this.name = in_name;
                  this.says = in_says;
            }

            public void run() {
                  if(Test.threads_counter >= Test.MAX_THREADS) {
                        try {
                              Thread.sleep(this.DELAY);
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                              Test.addResponse("Thread error");
                        }
                        this.run();
                        return;
                  }

                  Test.threads_counter++;
                  try {
                        for(int i = 0; i < this.REPEATS; ++i) {
                              Test.addResponse(this.name + " says \"" + this.says + "\"");
                              Thread.sleep(this.DELAY);
                        }
                  } catch(Exception e) {
                        Test.addResponse("And error occured for Thread " + this.name);
                  } finally {
                        Test.addResponse("Thread " + this.name + " stopping");
                        Test.threads_counter--;
                  }
            }
      }
```

and my attempt looks like this:

```
public void connect(){
    For(String id:idList){
      String url="...."+id;
      ThreadClass thread= new ThreadClas(url);
      Thread t = new Thread(thread);
       t.start();
    }
}
class ThreadClass implements Runnable{
   public final int MAX_THREADS = 10;
   public int threads_counter = 0; 

   public void run() {
       while(this.threads_counter >= this.MAX_THREADS){
          //sleep
        }
       threads_counter++;
       //fetch data and parse
       threads_counter--;
   }
}
```

But this is creating the thread and is just pausing it, so I am thinking that it would consume the RAM as if it was running anyway and considering that I have a good few thousands of ids, that would definitely cause me problems.
So, it would make more sense if I could block the creation of the thread in the main class. How could I do this? If I use a counter(as in the above example), I don’t know when each thread is terminated in order to start creating new threads.
On the other hand I have seen the `wait()/notify()` methods, but I am not sure how I can implement it, since I am creating new Objects, hence I cant notify them together.
I tried to read the Oracle's Java tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), but this confused me even more.

**Update**-*(not a)* solution
I did manage to change my classes to run as thread, using a pool (which was the right aproach for anyone having a similar error), but I was having connection issues (I am using a jdbc-mySql connection and a Secure Copy/Jcraft connection) and this was a trouble setting up properly. I was getting exceptions for connections being open(and/or closed) or having too many open connections, while trying to connect. I am guessing this was due to the fact that when i wrote the application I was opening and closing these connections inside the method that then turned to a Thread, causing to open multiple open connections. This was just too much truble to change right now, so I am just going to change back to single thread approach.

Maybe this should be a lesson for me to design my programs in a threaded oriented approach, and use it as a single thread if needed.

Comment: I suggest you use a ScheduledExecutorService. If you really have to use Threads directly, I recommend not subclassing Thread but wrapping a Runnable.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Executors and ThreadPools. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey what option do i have rather than using Threads "directly"? I am using Runnable, dont I?

Comment: @AlejandroC. Will look at the doc you provided. thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have `MyThread extends Thread` and the alternative for a periodic task is to use ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I dont `extends Thread`, i `implement Runnable`. The other code is from an example, i use runnable, since i want to extend an other class of my own later on anyway. will look into ScheduledExecutorService as well

Comment: @SkarosIlias I would advise to stay away from the website where you got that example from. Based on that code, it's extremely low quality.

Comment: @SkarosIlias I didn't realise you were showing us code you hadn't written. It seems more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 2):

> But this is creating the thread and is just pausing it,

Actually it's just burning CPU.

> so I am thinking that it would consume the RAM as if it was running anyway

It consumes CPU not RAM.

> and considering that I have a good few thousands of ids, that would definitely cause me problems.

It will cause problem once you have more threads than cores, most likely about 4.

> So, it would make more sense if I could block the creation of the thread in the main class. How could I do this?

I would use a Queue and pass it work, I would also use a Thread pool such as a fixed size thread pool if you want to limit the number of threads active.

> If I use a counter(as in the above example), I don’t know when each thread is terminated in order to start creating new threads.

You never will as your counter isn't thread save and the other thread might never see it update.

> On the other hand I have seen the wait()/notify() methods, but I am not sure how I can implement it, since I am creating new Objects, hence I cant notify them together.

You can pass them an object they can all look at, but like I said a fixed size thread pool Executor would be much simpler.

> I tried to read the Oracle's Java tutorial on Concurrency, but this confused me even more.

Since you want to process all the data and collect the results I suggest you use a parallelStream().

```
public void connect(){
    List<String> results = idList.parallelStream()
                                 .map(id -> fetchDataAndParse(id))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Some commnents on your answer first: 1)I thought that `thread.sleep()` doesnt use cpu! are you sure about that? 2)when the object is created and variables are initialised, isnt ram that is used and held for these variables? 2) havent thought about `Queues`, will consider them, combined with threads of course. 3)Could you provide an example of the wait/notify technique you mention? 4) I will have to look at `parallelStream()`, sever seen that before. Thanks

Comment: @SkarosIlias `Thread.sleep(1)` doesn't use CPU but `//sleep` busy waits.

Comment: @SkarosIlias yes it is but you will run out of CPU (and allowed threads) long before you run out of RAM , You could have one million of these objects easily. wait/notify wasn't best practice ten years ago when Java 5.0 came out, If you find multi-threading confusing I would seriously avoid it (and even then ...)

Answer (score 1):

> I haven’t figured out how to limit the Threads I create.

That strongly indicates that you want a fixed size thread *pool*.  See Peter (+1) Lawry's answer, above.

> I thought to give threads a try, in case it speeds thing up.

There are basically two reasons for using threads in any program:

1) To do *parallel computations* on a machine that has more than one CPU.  (When I say "computation", It could be math, or it could be almost anything else that your program does where it is uses a lot of CPU time without doing much IO.)

2) To simplify the structure of a program that models different abstract processes that are driven by different, independent (or partly independent) sources of external events.

In a single-threaded *event driven* program, a main *event loop* has to receive, and classify all of the different kinds of event, and then invoke *handlers* that drive the various processes.  The state of each process must be explicitly encoded in data structures that persist between handler invocations.  Understanding what is happening in such a program can be a challenge.

In a multi-threaded program, each abstract process can be modelled by its own thread, and much of the state of the process can be implicitly represented by the thread's program counter and call stack.  A multi-threaded program often is much easier to *read* than the equivalent event-driven program.  But threads have challenges of their own, and writing a *correct* multi-threaded program can be challenging in its own right.